# Is it acceptable to post questions to the OP as an answer?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Answer or comment: what's the etiquette?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17447/answer-or-comment-whats-the-etiquette)

Looking at this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014249/java-to-c-conversion/4014279#4014279

One of the answers isn't an answer, but some questions to the OP ('where does the error occur?', etc). I don't think this should be an answer, and asked about it, and the answerer ([George Stocker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16587/george-stocker)) gave roughly the following reasons:

- Answers have permenance, comments do not.  if the comments get deleted, the answer will remain.
- The OP will be notified by email of the answer, but not comments

I don't think these are valid reasons to post something which (IMO) isn't an answer as an answer, instead of a comment.  But this guy has a fair bit of rep and has been on SO longer than me, so maybe he knows something I don't.

is this a valid use of an answer?

Comment: For shame, Gortok, for shame

Comment: Do not ever be intimidated by high EXP users who can't use the site properly

Comment: @random I'd +1 your second comment, but I just got to know the comment vote limit :(

Comment: I don't know about email notification for comments, but comments are just as permanent as answers are (unless of course they are flagged and deleted, but his question would have made a fitting comment so why'd anyone do that?)

Comment: We should burn him at the stake.

Comment: @George Stocker: you shouldn't take this personal, but it's a bit confusing to see a high-rep user doing something new users are discouraged to do

Comment: @Tobias Why would I take it 'personal'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they are not answers.

There is a gray area for new users that are not able to use comments yet. But generally it is not acceptable (and possible target for downvotes).

Comment: Too bad George has around 15k rep at SO, so that excuse does not count for him